# In Android Studio 2.0, Cannot find local variable of method in debug mode

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

After Updating the android version 1.5 to 2.0 Preview4. Android studio Debugger unable to find the local variable defined in method definition. For reference, find the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: if this solved your pboelm , could you accept the answer.

Answer (score 89):

In your gradle, do you enable test coverage ?

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

Set `testCoverageEnabled = false` , it fixed the issue.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78045

Comment: Made AS see a pair of variables but further errors appear.

Comment: Thanks, it really helped!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! Ended up creating a boolean based on if the build is running on a dev machine or a CICD server (based on the presence of environment variables in our build environment) so it can still provide test coverage reports on a build pipeline.

Comment: @AniFichadia good idea. We do similar : set a environment variable on the CI , if this env. var. is not present ( on a developer's machine) the boolean default value is false.

Comment: +100500 rep for this answer, saved me a lot of time. Thx

Comment: In my case I had to put it to true when using jacoco if I want jacoco to produce coverage report. Put it back to false otherwise. Yeay!

Comment: I tried `create("customDebugType") {debuggable = true}` with and without `testCoverageEnabled = false`. I still get a wall of `view = Cannot find local variable 'view'` until it's done executing. I'm strugging to simply setup the ClickListener, and the items in the RecyclerView don't appear.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you are not building a `'Release'` Build Variant. You will get above warning when it is a Release Build.

Answer (score 9):

if you have  minifyEnabled true in

debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable true
        }

remove that and using just like that
  debug {
            debuggable true
        }

its work for me

Answer (score 6):

Disable jack for debug build type (build.gradle):

```
buildTypes {
    ...
    debug {
        jackOptions {
            enabled false
        }
    }
}
```

Note: 1.8 source compatibility requires jack!

Comment: So,  this means we cannot debug with Java 1.8, right?

Comment: No. It is possible to debug with java 1.8 and jack (breakpoints, step by step execution, etc.), but the values of the local variables are nor shown. Please note: my solution is a workaround not a resolution of the problem!

Comment: @Dori Android issue #93730 was closed as duplicate of another unrelated issue. I've created https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219615 as new issue related to "As soon as Jack & Jill are enabled, Android Studio does not show local variables and is unable to set breakpoints in library projects".

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution - open the Android Device Monitor, do a 'Reset adb'.

A screenshot where to find 'Reset adb'.

[image: A screenshot where to find 'Reset adb']

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you build configuration with debuggable flag.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I got the problem , it was in **build.gradle** file

buildTypes {
        debug{
            minifyEnabled true    //This was the problem , make it false

```
    }
    release{

    }
}
```