# Cannot find local variable

Tags: android-studio

As is seen from the screenshot, cant pass second parameter. I'm sure that position parameter is not null when calling insertTrack method.

I'v looked similar questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566901/in-android-studio-2-0-cannot-find-local-variable-of-method-in-debug-mode) but it didn't solve.

Can anyone explain me what's my mistake ?

[image]

Comment: Please try the solution with the adb reset that I've described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39469287/4733625)

Answer (score 2):

you may open `minifyEnabled`,try close it。I slove it by close `minifyEnabled`。

Answer (score 1):

you may not open **debuggable**.

```
buildTypes {
......
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        jniDebuggable true
        debuggable true
    }
......
}
```

[steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pdzo.png)